Image downloaded by Scrapy "may be damaged"/could not be opened
Here's an example of URL I'd like to download.
My custom image pipeline:
class MyImagePipeline(FilesPipeline):
    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        meta = {
            'folder_name': item.get('uuid'),
        }        
        if item.get('file_urls'):
            for image_url in item.get('file_urls'):
                yield scrapy.Request(image_url, meta=meta)
            
            
    def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None, *, item=None):
        image_guid = hashlib.sha1(request.url.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
        file_name = f'{image_guid}.jpg'
        return '%s/%s' % (request.meta["folder_name"], file_name)

This code downloads the image from the provided URL to the designated folder. The problem is that the image is unreadable - it cannot be opened:

This is an example of the URL address from where I am trying to download images:
Because in the URL is not stated the file extension of the image, I cannot dynamically set it in the file_name - so I just hard-code there .jpg. I tried to use there also .jpeg and .png, but the downloaded image is still not possible to open.
I am stuck here and I don't know what's causing the image not being able to open. Am I overlooking anything?
EDIT: cat filename.jpg:


What does the file actually contain?

Try opening the file with a text-editor to see if you can locate any errors at the start of the file

@wRAR I opened the file with the cat command (added image to OP) and there are some bytes in it.

@DarkBee Looks like a bunch of bytes. I cannot really read it, as it is mostly symbols. I just tried to open a "normal" file and the content of the file is very similar - a bunch of symbols

Doesn't look like it's an JPG though, see this reference list

What can I do with it? Did I set some parameters in Scrapy wrong? Or is there any way around? I just created a simple Scrapy project (no images/files pipelines involved) with yield scrapy.Request(url=image_url, callback=self.save_image, meta={'image_name': image_name}) and saving the image as with open(image_name, 'wb') as f:             f.write(response.body) and in this case, the image gets saved on the disk properly. Am I doing something wrong with the pipelines?

@DarkBee The URL contains an image and it's displayed as an image in a browser. What's preventing Scrapy from downloading it as an image?

I don't know scrappy well enough, but it's definitely not downloading the image atm. If you check the bytecode of the linked image you'll see they don't match. You should check the response you are receiving before saving it.
