Scrapy (Pillow) does not recognize an image from URL, but the same image from disk Pillow recognizes. Why?
I am using the following code to scrape images from the web.
class MyImagePipeline(FilesPipeline):
    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        meta = {
            'folder_name': item.get('uuid'),
        }        
        if item.get('file_urls'):
            for image_url in item.get('file_urls'):
                yield scrapy.Request(image_url, meta=meta)
            
            
    def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None, *, item=None):
        image_guid = hashlib.sha1(request.url.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
        file_name = f'{image_guid}.jpg'
        return '%s/%s' % (request.meta["folder_name"], file_name)

However, when I run Scrapy, I get this error:
DEBUG: File (downloaded): Downloaded file from <GET https://pictures.immobilienscout24.de/prod.www.immobilienscout24.at/pictureserver/loadPicture?q=70&id=012.0012000001E3qxe-1724758328-b45723a13abc4ebbb72758ac00706366> referred in <None>
ERROR: File (unknown-error): Error processing file from <GET https://pictures.immobilienscout24.de/prod.www.immobilienscout24.at/pictureserver/loadPicture?q=70&id=012.0012000001E3qxe-1724758328-b45723a13abc4ebbb72758ac00706366> referred in <None>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/adam/project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scrapy/pipelines/files.py", line 493, in media_downloaded
    checksum = self.file_downloaded(response, request, info, item=item)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/adam/project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scrapy/pipelines/media.py", line 153, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/adam/project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scrapy/pipelines/images.py", line 119, in file_downloaded
    return self.image_downloaded(response, request, info, item=item)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/adam/project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scrapy/pipelines/media.py", line 153, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/adam/project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scrapy/pipelines/images.py", line 123, in image_downloaded
    for path, image, buf in self.get_images(response, request, info, item=item):
  File "/Users/adam/project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scrapy/pipelines/images.py", line 139, in get_images
    orig_image = self._Image.open(BytesIO(response.body))
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/adam/project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 3498, in open
    raise UnidentifiedImageError(msg)
PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x113d93290>
ERROR: [Failure instance: Traceback: <class 'scrapy.pipelines.files.FileException'>: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x113d93290>

Needless to say, the respective image is visible in the browser. When I right-click the image, save it to my local disc and check it with this script:
from PIL import Image

def is_image(file_path):
    try:
        # Attempt to open the file as an image
        with Image.open(file_path) as img:
            img.verify()
        return True
    except (IOError, SyntaxError, Image.UnidentifiedImageError) as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
        return False

# Example usage
file_path = '/Users/adam/test_img.jpg'
if is_image(file_path):
    print(f"{file_path} is a valid image.")
else:
    print(f"{file_path} is not a valid image.")

Then the output from the script is /Users/adam/test_img.jpg is a valid image.
Thus, my question is - I can see the image properly in the browser, I can download it from the browser to my computer and open it there - and it looks exactly the same as in the browser.
When I check this image file with a Python script that uses Pillow (that Scrapy uses as well), it properly validates the image.
However, Scapy (that uses Pillow as well) cannot recognize this image and is throwing an error. Why is that happening and Scrapy cannot read the image?

Isn't the problem the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78913060/image-downloaded-by-scrapy-may-be-damaged-could-not-be-opened ?

The content of the image is valid, as your script checked.
But the error messages you post show that the error occurs at:
self._Image.open(BytesIO(response.body))

which means the response of the request to that image was invalid.
It's about how you get the content of the image, not the content itself.
You should debug the response of the request to the image to see if the header and body of the response were correct.
Usually, the reason could be:

Parameters were not set correctly in the header of request, such as
User-Agent, Referer or Accept.
Connection was banned by the remote
server, or using a bad proxy.
And so on.


thank you. I have probably a stupid question, but where exactly in the Scrapy workflow can I investigate the body and headers of the downloaded image? There are methods in the custom pipeline - get_media_requests and file_path, but this information do not appear to be available there? And in the spider/parse method, I can obviously access the item with all scraped information, but I think there are no headers/body specifically to the image?

@user984621 You can set a breakpoint in file_path function and run in debug mode to see the response parameter, or save the body and headers of response to a local file.
